# Sort column elements in reverse order by row ID

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column of numbers in Excel:

```
    column A
row ----------
 1   2.11
 2   1.123
 3   2.222
 4   ...
 5   ...
 6   ...
```

What I want to do is sort those in reverse order by row number (not by the value in the cell), meaning as a result I will get the following:

```
    column A
row ----------
 1   ...
 2   ...
 3   ...
 4   2.222
 5   1.123
 6   2.11
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: To clarify, you want to define a range of values and then sort in descending order based on the row number?  You show the row number, itself in descending order, but can I assume that is just to identify where the value came from (you can't actually change the numbers of the row identifiers)?

Comment: It's a shame you decided to provide sample data that actually sorts into the order that you are looking for. Random values would have helped clarify the problem.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do that. Your question already has an answer [here](http://superuser.com/questions/28813/reverse-order-of-rows-in-excel/28819#28819)

Answer (score 0):

I end up writing javascript to do that for me, here's the code:

```
var total_coordinates = 0;
var coordinates_array = [];
var doneReading = false;

function loadCoordinatesFile() {
    var oFrame = document.getElementById('coordinatesFrame');
    var oFrameReOrdered = document.getElementById('coordinatesFrameReorderd');
    var strRawContents = oFrame.contentWindow.document.body.childNodes[0].innerHTML;
    while (strRawContents.indexOf("\r") >= 0)
        strRawContents = strRawContents.replace("\r", "");
    var arrLines = strRawContents.split("\n");
    for (var i = arrLines.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        console.log("line = " + arrLines[i]);
        var curLine = arrLines[i];
        total_coordinates = total_coordinates + 1;
        coordinates_array.push(curLine);
        oFrameReOrdered.contentWindow.document.write(curLine + "<br>");
    }
}
```